# What does ^d mean in ls -l | grep ^d?

Tags: command-line, grep, special-characters

When I do `ls -l | grep ^d` it lists only directories in the current directory.

What I'd like to know is what does the caret `^` in `^d` mean?

Comment: For related information, look up regular expressions or check out this page on using regular expressions in grep: http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/regexpr.html

Comment: This works, but is suboptimal.  Consider `ls */` instead, which will work with or without the long listing (`ls -l`) and without needing `grep` (and thus is very slightly faster) and is less likely (than `ls -l *`) to run into an [argument list too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289551/argument-list-too-long-error-for-rm-cp-mv-commands) issue (since it puts just directories into the command line).  Of course, `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d` is even better, as it doesn't clutter your command line at all.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Andy's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3077/what-does-d-mean-in-ls-l-grep-d/3079#3079) is correct, as seen in the man page:

> **Anchoring**
>
> The caret ^ and the dollar sign $ are meta-characters that respectively match the empty string at the beginning and end of a line.

The reason it works is the `-l` flag to `ls` makes it use the long-listing format. The first thing shown in each line is the human-readable permissions for the file, and the first character of that is either `d` for a directory or `-` for a file

Answer (score 18):

That's a caret, not a carrot.  It means "beginning of the line."  The grep is matching only lines that start with "d".